# Errot: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'tostring') javascript

Tags: javascript, typeerror, tostring

Hello guys I get this error message: "NFA_definitions.js:89 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')".
I have these 2 methods inside a class in my code:

```
toDotString() {
    let dotStr = "digraph fsm {\n";
    dotStr += "rankdir=LR;\n";
    dotStr += 'size="8,5";\n';
    dotStr += "node [shape = point]; INITIAL_STATE\n";
    dotStr +=
      "node [shape = doublecircle]; " + this.finalStates.join(",") + ";\n";
    dotStr += "node [shape = circle];\n";
    dotStr +=
      "INITIAL_STATE -> " + this.formatDotState(this.initialState) + ";\n";

    for (let i = 0; i < this.transitions.length; i++) {
      let t = this.transitions[i];

      dotStr +=
        "" +
        this.formatDotState(t.state) +
        " -> " +
        this.formatDotState(t.nextStates) +
        " [label=" +
        t.symbol +
        "];\n";
    }

    dotStr += "}";

    return dotStr;
  }

  formatDotState(state_str) {
    state_str = state_str.toString();
    if (isMultiState(state_str)) {
      state_str = state_str.substring(1, state_str.length - 1);
      state_str = state_str.replace(/,/g, "");
      return state_str;
    } else {
      return state_str;
    }
  }
```

And for some reason I get an error in the toString method. This is the error that shows up at the console:

```
NFA_definitions.js:89 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString')
    at NFA.formatDotState (NFA_definitions.js:89:27)
    at NFA.toDotString (NFA_definitions.js:75:14)
    at HTMLHeadingElement.<anonymous> (NFA_functionality.js:117:18)
    at HTMLHeadingElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:2:43064)
    at y.handle (jquery.min.js:2:41048)
    at Object.trigger (jquery.min.js:2:71659)
    at HTMLHeadingElement.<anonymous> (jquery.min.js:2:72254)
    at Function.each (jquery.min.js:2:3003)
    at S.fn.init.each (jquery.min.js:2:1481)
    at S.fn.init.trigger (jquery.min.js:2:72230)
```

Can someone help me and tell me what is wrong with my code. I am like a week and i cannot find what is happening!

Comment: `t.state` or `t.nextStates` is undefined for some elements. `console.log(this.transitions)` and debug your code

Answer (score 0):

Maybe `this.transitions` contains empty elements.

What you can do to reinforce your code and avoid having "Cannot read properties of undefined" is to secure your variable before applying the `toString()` like below:

```js
formatDotState(state_str) {
    state_str = (state_str || '').toString(); // <-- update this line
    if (isMultiState(state_str)) {
      state_str = state_str.substring(1, state_str.length - 1);
      state_str = state_str.replace(/,/g, "");
      return state_str;
    } else {
      return state_str;
    }
  }
```

Comment: It means that if `state_str` received from an object of `this.transitions` where properties `state` or `nextStates` are potentially invalid, then you can reassign it to an empty string with the synthax: `myValue || ''`.